# Is there a way to automatically format all of your source code indentation in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coding-style, resharper

I know all about "format on save" and ctrl+k+d, but i want to format ALL of my source code from 2 spaces to 4 spaces, in 1 single commit..

Is there any extension or tool for making visual studio do it for the  ALL solution/project?
(I have resharper!)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what want. Can you elaborate

Comment: edited post to try to make it clearer. I have code, several thousand files, with the identation of 2 spaces, i want to change that to 4 spaces, but instead of editing file by file I want a tool for it....

Comment: I'm not sure can with vanilla visual studio, you might have to format each file, with resharper you can do a cleanup on a solution or project though

Comment: something like [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html) ? epecially the [Reformat existing code in any scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html#4a9db58b) section

Comment: I found it also, thanks Mong Zhu!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently resharper can do it for the all solution, you just select the solution and click in the following [image]